# New Solr Core data

Tags: solr

I have an existing solr core which has data in it regarding info on oil. It runs great.

This morning I created a new solr core in the same container having to do with info on water.

Both cores are now running well with their respective schema files, config files, etc. However, when I go to the newly created oil core in firefox the water data is somehow already in it. Like both cores are sharing the same %SOLR_HOME%/data.

How in Solr when I create a new core can I ensure it does not share data with another existing core? I essentially want to do the opposite of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2502393/how-do-i-create-a-solr-core-with-the-data-from-an-existing-one).

**EDIT** The way I created the water core was to copy the oil core and rename the directory as well as rename the schema file along with copying the oil war and renaming it to water so that Tomcat could build a fresh web directory for water. Not sure if that has any barring on this, but just in case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you copied the entire oil core directory, including the data/index directory (if you are following the default folder naming conventions). This index folder contains all of the data from the oil core. So in this case if you copy one core to reuse as the starting point for another core, I would recommend deleting any folders that are in the data directory of the new core after copying it over. This will keep all of the other settings, but clear out the data as the index (and other folders) will be created when the core is started.

Comment: In your 3rd sentence do you mean recommending to 'delete' any folder that are in the data dir?

Comment: Yes, I left out the word "deleting". Thanks for pointing that out and that it worked for you.